# Почему при полиморфизме нужно использовать динамический массив, а не статический?

Tags: c++, указатели, c++11, полиморфизм

Есть абстрактный класс Human

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
class Human
{
protected:
    string name;
    int age;
    int exp;
    int magicNumber;
public:
    Human(void);
    Human(string name, int age, int exp);
    ~Human(void);
public:
    int getMagic();
    void Print();
public:
    virtual bool Shoot();
    virtual double getCoef();
};
```

```
bool Human::Shoot()
{
    return false;
}
```

у него 3 наследника(Beginner, Experienced, Veteran), в которых переопределяется функция Shoot

```
bool Beginner::Shoot()
{
    return (0.01 * exp > magicNumber) ? true : false;
}
```

Если использовать динамический массив, то полиморфизм прекрасно работает и вызываются функции наследников класса.

```
Human **shooters = new Human*[7];
    shooters[0] = new Beginner("Ivan", 22, 3000);
    shooters[1] = new Beginner("Sasha", 17, 1500);
    shooters[2] = new Beginner("Dasha", 20, 3300);
    shooters[3] = new Experienced("Hitman", 29, 6500);
    shooters[4] = new Veteran("Polkovnik", 55, 10000);
    shooters[5] = new Experienced("Motorolla", 35, 7000);
    shooters[6] = new Beginner("Maxim", 22, 4000);

    
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout << shooters[i]->getMagic() << " : " << shooters[i]->getCoef() <<((shooters[i]->Shoot()) ? "Попал" : "Мимо!") << endl;
    }
```

Но если использовать статический массив, будет вызываться виртуальный метод базового класса.

```
Human shooters[7] = {Beginner("Ivan", 22, 3000),
        Beginner("Sasha", 17, 1500),
        Beginner("Dasha", 20, 3300),
        Experienced("Hitman", 29, 6500),
        Veteran("Polkovnik", 55, 10000),
        Experienced("Motorolla", 35, 7000),
        Beginner("Maxim", 22, 4000)};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout << shooters[i].getMagic() << " : " << shooters[i].getCoef() <<((shooters[i].Shoot()) ? "Попал" : "Мимо!") << endl;
    }
```

**Внимание вопрос**: Почему так?

Comment: *"Есть абстрактный класс Human"* - в приведенном примере класс `Human` не является абстрактным. Именно поэтому компилятор позволяет создавать массив экземпляров этого класса `Human shooters[7]`. Соответственно потом вы вызываете виртуальный метод у экземпляров базового класса, Ни один экземпляр дочерних классов в этот массив попасть не может.

Comment: Но если я создаю, массив указателей, то все прекрасно работает. И я не понимаю почему так

Comment: Потому что указатель (или ссылка) на базовый класс может указывать как на экземпляр базового класса, так и на экземпляр дочернего класса. А когда написано, что в массиве хранятся экземпляры класса `Human` , то только они там и будут хранится.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ предоставил @user7860670 в комментариях.

> Указатель (или ссылка) на базовый класс может указывать как на экземпляр базового класса, так и на экземпляр дочернего класса. А когда написано, что в массиве хранятся экземпляры класса Human , то только они там и будут хранится.

Comment: То есть разница в не в типе массива (статический/динамический), а в типе элемента — экземпляр или указатель

Answer (score 1):

Переменная или элемент массива базового типа **Human** имеют фиксированный размер и тип, и физически не может быть другим родственным объектом, так как даже размер другого типа может быть просто больше.

Если вы используете массив **указателей** `new Human*[7];` , то элемент как указатель может указывать на разные типы. А создание массива **объектов** `Human shooters[7]` может вмещать в себя **только** элемент базового класса.
И дальнейшее присвоение элементу массива `shooters[0] = Beginner("Ivan", 22, 3000);` просто **обрезает** тип до базового, и от дочернего объекта ничего не остаётся.

Любой массив можно использовать. Статический или динамический. Даже сами объекты могут быть статическими. Самое главное, чтобы был массив **указателей**. Так как они могут указывать на элементы любого класса, а размер указателей одинаков.

---

Неправильно так :

```
Human shooters[7];
```

или

```
Human * shooters = new Human [7];
```

---

, а правильно так :

```
Human * shooters[7];
shooters[3] = new Beginner(...);
Beginner alex;
shooters[4] = & alex;
```

или

```
Human * * shooters = new Human * [7];
shooters[3] = new Beginner(...);
Beginner alex;
shooters[4] = & alex;
```